# Tastypie access resource by parameter other than PK

Tags: python, django, api, tastypie

I am having a hard time figuring out how to ask this question.

I have a model `User`. Currently when I want to access a specific user I go to the url: `/api/v1/user/8/`. Although, all users have unique usernames, so I would like to go to a specific user by using the url: `/api/v1/user/joe/`.

Maybe something with `prepend_urls()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `detail_uri_name` in your `ModelResource`'s `Meta` class ([documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html#detail-uri-name)) - example resources.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource


class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        detail_uri_name = 'username'
```